# Facebook "Requests Dialog" - multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

wiki source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

img screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyYin.jpg

is it posible to preselect multiple users (where is Naitik Shah) in this dialog?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When preselecting, you can only specify 1 user ID. If you don't specify any user IDs, then Facebook pops up a friend select dialog and the user can select up to 50 friends. If you want to send to multiple users, the user has to do the selecting.

Comment: I wish I could vote for your answer ... but my reputation does not allow this :/